# How to parse XML into flatfile or any relational db without using any ETL tool

Tags: sql-server, xml, api, t-sql, xml-parsing

I am having some assignment to produce the records from XML into CSV or any database. I know if I can use ETL tool it would be easier, but my client wants to use some method which can be parse those XML in CSV or in any relational db like sql server without any complexity. If it can possible to using some API or some javascript/tsql or may be some other method which i may not aware.

I need to share some idea which can be used here either within a single method or making it in two method like first XML to CSV and then CSV to sql. for second approach i can use sqloader, but for the first method i need some help. I am sharing my XML here, and the output which I am expecting. Please share your idea or any code snippet if anyone can share with me.

For further input these XML i am getting every month from API output like postman. so if its possible to use all together that also will be good. I have multiple XML which need to be parsed together, here i am sharing one sample XML.

and one sample area like [https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014](http://dbfiddle) where i can test your code. You can save the file and File1.xml

All kind of suggestion is welcome. Thanks in Advance.

**Input XML**

```
<feed xmlns="pppp//www.xxx.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:m="pppp//xxxx/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="pppp//xxxx/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xml:base="pppp//BW.SAP.SETS.EU:443/sap/opu/odata/sap/SSC_24_KPI/">
        <id>pppp//pppp//xxxx/id</id>
        <title type="text">SSC_24_KPI_V1Results</title>
        <updated>2019-11-08T13:37:56Z</updated>
        <author>
            <name/>
        </author>
        <link href="SSC_24_KPI_V1Results" rel="self" title="SSC_24_KPI_V1Results"/>
        <entry>
            <id>pppp//pppp//xxxx/id('V2.77.5')</id>
            <title type="text">SSC_24_KPI_V1Results('V2.77.5')</title>
            <updated>2019-11-08T13:37:56Z</updated>
            <category term="SSC_24_KPI.SSC_24_KPI_V1Results" scheme="pppp//xxxx/scheme"/>
            <link href="SSC_24_KPI_V1Results('V2.77.5')" rel="self" title="SSC_24_KPI_V1Results"/>
            <content type="application/xml">
                <m:prop xmlns:m="pppp//xxxx/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="pppp//xxxx/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
                    <d:ACCNT_GRP_ID>Z001</d:ACCNT_GRP_ID>
                    <d:ACCT_GRP>EU Bank</d:ACCT_GRP>
                    <d:VAY_FLAG>N</d:VAY_FLAG>
                    <d:CUST_COUNT>15600</d:CUST_COUNT>
                </m:prop>
            </content>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <id>pppp//pppp//xxxx/id('V2.77.6')</id>
            <title type="text">SSC_24_KPI_V1Results('V2.77.6')</title>
            <updated>2019-11-08T13:37:56Z</updated>
            <category term="SSC_24_KPI.SSC_24_KPI_V1Results" scheme="pppp//xxxx/scheme"/>
            <link href="SSC_24_KPI_V1Results('V2.77.6')" rel="self" title="SSC_24_KPI_V1Results"/>
            <content type="application/xml">
                <m:prop xmlns:m="pppp//xxxx/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="pppp//xxxx/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
                    <d:ACCNT_GRP_ID>Z001</d:ACCNT_GRP_ID>
                    <d:ACCT_GRP>EU Bank</d:ACCT_GRP>
                    <d:VAY_FLAG>Y</d:VAY_FLAG>
                    <d:CUST_COUNT>900</d:CUST_COUNT>
                </m:prop>
            </content>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <id>pppp//pppp//xxxx/id('V2.77.7')</id>
            <title type="text">SSC_24_KPI_V1Results('V2.77.7')</title>
            <updated>2019-11-08T13:37:56Z</updated>
            <category term="SSC_24_KPI.SSC_24_KPI_V1Results" scheme="pppp//xxxx/scheme"/>
            <link href="SSC_24_KPI_V1Results('V2.77.7')" rel="self" title="SSC_24_KPI_V1Results"/>
            <content type="application/xml">
                <m:prop xmlns:m="pppp//xxxx/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="pppp//xxxx/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
                    <d:ACCNT_GRP_ID>Z002</d:ACCNT_GRP_ID>
                    <d:ACCT_GRP>Card Companies NO</d:ACCT_GRP>
                    <d:VAY_FLAG>N</d:VAY_FLAG>
                    <d:CUST_COUNT>100</d:CUST_COUNT>
                </m:prop>
            </content>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <id>pppp//pppp//xxxx/id('V2.77.8')</id>
            <title type="text">SSC_24_KPI_V1Results('V2.77.8')</title>
            <updated>2019-11-08T13:37:56Z</updated>
            <category term="SSC_24_KPI.SSC_24_KPI_V1Results" scheme="pppp//xxxx/scheme"/>
            <link href="SSC_24_KPI_V1Results('V2.77.8')" rel="self" title="SSC_24_KPI_V1Results"/>
            <content type="application/xml">
                <m:prop xmlns:m="pppp//xxxx/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="pppp//xxxx/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
                    <d:ACCNT_GRP_ID>Z002</d:ACCNT_GRP_ID>
                    <d:ACCT_GRP>Card Companies NO</d:ACCT_GRP>
                    <d:VAY_FLAG>Y</d:VAY_FLAG>
                    <d:CUST_COUNT>3000</d:CUST_COUNT>
                </m:prop>
            </content>
        </entry>
    </feed>
```

**Output** 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it like here:

Assumption: You know how to read this XML into a variable...

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<feed xmlns="pppp//www.xxx.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:m="pppp//xxxx/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="pppp//xxxx/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xml:base="pppp//BW.SAP.SETS.EU:443/sap/opu/odata/sap/SSC_24_KPI/">
  <id>pppp//pppp//xxxx/id</id>
  <title type="text">SSC_24_KPI_V1Results</title>
  <updated>2019-11-08T13:37:56Z</updated>
  <author>
    <name />
  </author>
  <link href="SSC_24_KPI_V1Results" rel="self" title="SSC_24_KPI_V1Results" />
  <entry>
    <id>pppp//pppp//xxxx/id(''V2.77.5'')</id>
    <title type="text">SSC_24_KPI_V1Results(''V2.77.5'')</title>
    <updated>2019-11-08T13:37:56Z</updated>
    <category term="SSC_24_KPI.SSC_24_KPI_V1Results" scheme="pppp//xxxx/scheme" />
    <link href="SSC_24_KPI_V1Results(''V2.77.5'')" rel="self" title="SSC_24_KPI_V1Results" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:prop xmlns:m="pppp//xxxx/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="pppp//xxxx/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
        <d:ACCNT_GRP_ID>Z001</d:ACCNT_GRP_ID>
        <d:ACCT_GRP>EU Bank</d:ACCT_GRP>
        <d:VAY_FLAG>N</d:VAY_FLAG>
        <d:CUST_COUNT>15600</d:CUST_COUNT>
      </m:prop>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>pppp//pppp//xxxx/id(''V2.77.6'')</id>
    <title type="text">SSC_24_KPI_V1Results(''V2.77.6'')</title>
    <updated>2019-11-08T13:37:56Z</updated>
    <category term="SSC_24_KPI.SSC_24_KPI_V1Results" scheme="pppp//xxxx/scheme" />
    <link href="SSC_24_KPI_V1Results(''V2.77.6'')" rel="self" title="SSC_24_KPI_V1Results" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:prop xmlns:m="pppp//xxxx/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="pppp//xxxx/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
        <d:ACCNT_GRP_ID>Z001</d:ACCNT_GRP_ID>
        <d:ACCT_GRP>EU Bank</d:ACCT_GRP>
        <d:VAY_FLAG>Y</d:VAY_FLAG>
        <d:CUST_COUNT>900</d:CUST_COUNT>
      </m:prop>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>pppp//pppp//xxxx/id(''V2.77.7'')</id>
    <title type="text">SSC_24_KPI_V1Results(''V2.77.7'')</title>
    <updated>2019-11-08T13:37:56Z</updated>
    <category term="SSC_24_KPI.SSC_24_KPI_V1Results" scheme="pppp//xxxx/scheme" />
    <link href="SSC_24_KPI_V1Results(''V2.77.7'')" rel="self" title="SSC_24_KPI_V1Results" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:prop xmlns:m="pppp//xxxx/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="pppp//xxxx/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
        <d:ACCNT_GRP_ID>Z002</d:ACCNT_GRP_ID>
        <d:ACCT_GRP>Card Companies NO</d:ACCT_GRP>
        <d:VAY_FLAG>N</d:VAY_FLAG>
        <d:CUST_COUNT>100</d:CUST_COUNT>
      </m:prop>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>pppp//pppp//xxxx/id(''V2.77.8'')</id>
    <title type="text">SSC_24_KPI_V1Results(''V2.77.8'')</title>
    <updated>2019-11-08T13:37:56Z</updated>
    <category term="SSC_24_KPI.SSC_24_KPI_V1Results" scheme="pppp//xxxx/scheme" />
    <link href="SSC_24_KPI_V1Results(''V2.77.8'')" rel="self" title="SSC_24_KPI_V1Results" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:prop xmlns:m="pppp//xxxx/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="pppp//xxxx/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
        <d:ACCNT_GRP_ID>Z002</d:ACCNT_GRP_ID>
        <d:ACCT_GRP>Card Companies NO</d:ACCT_GRP>
        <d:VAY_FLAG>Y</d:VAY_FLAG>
        <d:CUST_COUNT>3000</d:CUST_COUNT>
      </m:prop>
    </content>
  </entry>
</feed>';
```

--The query

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'pppp//www.xxx.org/2005/Atom' 
                  ,'pppp//xxxx/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata' AS m
                  ,'pppp//xxxx/ado/2007/08/dataservices' AS d
                  ,'pppp//BW.SAP.SETS.EU:443/sap/opu/odata/sap/SSC_24_KPI/' AS base)
select @xml.value('(/feed/updated/text())[1]','datetime') AS UPDATED
      ,entr.value('(content/m:prop/d:ACCNT_GRP_ID/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS ACCNT_GRP_ID
      ,entr.value('(content/m:prop/d:ACCT_GRP/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS ACCT_GRP
      ,entr.value('(content/m:prop/d:VAY_FLAG/text())[1]','nvarchar(10)') AS VAY_FLAG
      ,entr.value('(content/m:prop/d:CUST_COUNT/text())[1]','nvarchar(10)') AS CUST_COUNT
FROM @xml.nodes('/feed/entry') A(entr);
```

The result

```
+-------------------------+--------------+-------------------+----------+------------+
| UPDATED                 | ACCNT_GRP_ID | ACCT_GRP          | VAY_FLAG | CUST_COUNT |
+-------------------------+--------------+-------------------+----------+------------+
| 2019-11-08 13:37:56.000 | Z001         | EU Bank           | N        | 15600      |
+-------------------------+--------------+-------------------+----------+------------+
| 2019-11-08 13:37:56.000 | Z001         | EU Bank           | Y        | 900        |
+-------------------------+--------------+-------------------+----------+------------+
| 2019-11-08 13:37:56.000 | Z002         | Card Companies NO | N        | 100        |
+-------------------------+--------------+-------------------+----------+------------+
| 2019-11-08 13:37:56.000 | Z002         | Card Companies NO | Y        | 3000       |
+-------------------------+--------------+-------------------+----------+------------+
```

The idea in short:

- There are various namespaces, which need to be declared at the beginning.
- Repeating elements (the `<entry>` elements) are retrieved with `.nodes()`.
- From these repeating `entr`-rows we can read with a relative XPath.
- Header data (everything living just once within your XML) is read directly using `.value()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It was really helpful to me. As I am new to this. But i am not aware how to take xml file into variable. I can execute your code in dbfiddle and it is working. But in real time i have physical files which comes in server. How to get that files and read into a variable if you help me out.